# how to cleanup my dead actor in Scala

Tags: scala, actor

Hi 
I am using scala(2.8.1) to implement a time-consuming task handler using actor, however, I am not able to clean it up when running my unit tests, so my unit tests hung forever.

how I call the method is:

```
  val configs = new ProjectsConfig("XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  try {
    configs.start
    configs.init//time consuming stuff
  } finally {
    configs.destory
    configs.stop
  }
```

What I plan to do is to keep the actors' reference and call exit on each on, the code snippet is like this:

- init, initialize the actors and keep the reference of each actor.
- destory, call exit on each actor.
- stop, call exit on this actor.

however, it seems not working well. how to clean all actors in this case?

```
class ProjectsConfig(val url: String) extends Actor {
  private var actors: List[Actor] = List()
  private object Stop

  def init = {
    val caller = this;
    for (projectConfig <- list) {
      val myActor: Actor = actor {
        caller ! projectConfig.instantiate
      }
      actors = actors ::: List(myActor)
    }
  }

  def act() {
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case project: Project =>
          Projects.update(project)
        case Stop => exit()
      }
    }
  }

  def destory {
    for (actor <- actors) {
      try {
        actor ! exit
      } catch {
        case e => System.out.println(e.printStackTrace)
      }
    }
  }

  def stop() {
    this ! Stop
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) In your specific case, I would simplify

```
val myActor: Actor = actor {
caller ! projectConfig.instantiate
}
```

to just `caller ! projectConfig.instantiate`. You're already making a call from the actor's sub-system, so an additional wrapping is not needed.

Besides that, though it's generally recommended to call actors from the actors' environment (spawning the call), **it's not a "must" at all** (and no evil will happen, if you call the actor directly in a non-actor env). In your case, wrapping the calls rather adds problems (boilerplate and inconsistencies).

2) What's actually happening in `actor ! exit` is `actor ! Actor.exit` ([assuming that you have a wildcard import on `Actor`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src//actors/scala/actors/Actor.scala#L354)). This code throws an exception attempting to evaluate `Actor.exit`, and nothing is sent to the actor. In order to stop the actor, you must call `exit` on its instance. It can be done through a message-sending, that will call a protected `exit`:

```
actor{
  loop{
     react{
        case `exit => exit('stop)
     }
  }
}
```